# SQL Management Studio 19: what determines if action Script SP appends "collate database_default" or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I noticed that for some databases that I access with SQL Management Studio Version 19, even if those databases have the same default collation set (here: "Latin1_General_CI_AS") the output listing generated by Script Stored Procedure to a New Window emits defintions of temporaty tables that are used by that SP with "collate database_default" on one database and not on the other database.
Even if the original create procedure didn't define collation on the temp tables declared in the body, the action mentioned above adds it (or not, depending on some unknown by my condition).

Example:

If the original SP contains:

```
create table #tmp_flatfile
(
    PersonalNr  varchar(30) null,
)
```

Then the lines resulting from running Script SP to a New Window will look like this:

```
create table #tmp_flatfile
(
    PersonalNr  varchar(30) collate database_default null,
)
```

But sometimes they will not contain "collate database_default".
I have no idea what determines this behaviour.
Other question is why this is added in the first place, as it only defines that collation used is the default one.

Comment: "Even if the original create procedure didn't define collation on the temp tables declared in the body, the action mentioned above adds it" -- yeah, I don't think so. Management Studio treats the body of a stored procedure as a blob, since you can put (almost) any valid combination of T-SQL statements in there. The stored procedure should be scripted with exactly the text that was put into it, formatting and all. Management Studio will certainly not do things like rewrite `CREATE TABLE` statements included in the sproc. Double check your assumptions on what's being scripted.

Comment: There is no way SSMS would do this for stored procedures, where the SQL is stored in the DB as text. It only does this for real tables

Comment: SSMS doesn't generate that at all. It was in the script already. Most likely because the server's and hence TempDB's collation isn't `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, FYI, SSMS (SMO) doesn't simply treat textual object definitions as blobs. The text definition is parsed and, if the object name in the body differs from the actual name (i.e. the object was renamed), the resultant script will have the current name.

Comment: @DanGuzman: Alright, point to you for technical correctness, but practically speaking that's the *only* thing it does, right? It doesn't look past the `CREATE`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, AFAIK, SSMS only changes the name (if different) and optionally changes the `CREATE` to `ALTER` or `CREATE OR ALTER` per the scripting options.

Comment: As other says, the addition of collate is purely dependant on how procedure was created  originally and is on the whim of the developer writing the code. In my opinion, one should always use add collate database_default to all *temporary* tables create clauses, this simplifies joins between current and temp db tables, which is usually what you're doing. It won't help joining other databases though. It's also possible to reparse and add (or remove) this afterwards by you need some parsing skills for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary tables are generated in TempDB, not the database where the stored procedure is running. TempDB's collation is the same as the server's.

If the collation of your database and TempDB are different, you won't be able to JOIN with a temporary table at all without forcing the collation with `COLLATE` in the JOIN clause. If you do that, you won't be able to use any indexes that cover the JOIN columns.

If you use ASCII types like `varchar` you can end up with mangled or lost data too, as non-USASCII text gets transcoded between the different codepages.

This may sound as an unusual case, but even `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI` and `Latin1_General_CI_AI` are two *different* collations. If you restore a `Latin1_General_CI_AI` backup to a `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI` server you'll find that JOINs may fail.

That's something I found the hard way.

Without `collate database_default` you'd have two very painful options:

- Change the collation of all columns in your database to match the server or worse,
- Change the server's collation by rebuilding the system databases. And then you'd have to change the collation of all other databases too.